# Install rails error:Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am install rail on CentOS 7.2,this is my install command:

```
gem install rails -v=4.2
```

This is the error log output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# gem install rails -v=4.2
gem install rails -v=4.2Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/share/include/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/share/gems/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

CentOS: 7.2

Ruby: ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]

gem: 2.0.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install dependency:

```
yum -y install libyaml-devel zlib-devel curl-devel openssl-devel httpd-devel apr-devel apr-util-devel gcc ruby-devel gcc-c++ make postgresql-devel ImageMagick-devel sqlite-devel perl-LDAP mod_perl perl-Digest-SHA
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your system by using following command

```
gem update --system 2.0.3
```

Comment: Thank you ,I will try later